# Checking the object type in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, rtti, typeid

I have class B that inherits from A.

```
class A
{
};

class B : public A
{
};
```

And I have three objects.

```
A* a = new A();
A* a2 = new B();
B* b = new B();
```

I'd like to if check a is object of type A, a2 is object of type B (not A), and b is object of type B.

I tried typed comparison, but it doesn't give me correct answer.

```
cout << (typeid(*a) == typeid(A)) << endl; // -> 1
cout << (typeid(*a2) == typeid(A)) << endl; // -> 1
cout << (typeid(*b) == typeid(A)) << endl; // -> 0

cout << (typeid(*a) == typeid(B)) << endl; // -> 0
cout << (typeid(*a2) == typeid(B)) << endl; // -> 0
cout << (typeid(*b) == typeid(B)) << endl; // -> 1
```

I tried dynamic casting, but I got compile error.

```
B* derived = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
if (derived) {
    cout << "a is B";
}
derived = dynamic_cast<B*>(a2);
if (derived) {
    cout << "a2 is B";
}
derived = dynamic_cast<B*>(b);
if (derived) {
    cout << "b is B";
}

typename.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
typename.cpp:27:36: error: cannot dynamic_cast 'a' (of type 'class A*') to type 'class B*' (source type is not polymorphic)
     B* derived = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
                                    ^
typename.cpp:31:34: error: cannot dynamic_cast 'a2' (of type 'class A*') to type 'class B*' (source type is not polymorphic)
     derived = dynamic_cast<B*>(a2);
```

I used static casting, but I got the answer wrong.

```
B* derived = static_cast<B*>(a);
if (derived) {
    cout << "a is B"; // -> YES
}
derived = static_cast<B*>(a2);
if (derived) {
    cout << "a2 is B"; // -> YES
}
derived = dynamic_cast<B*>(b);
if (derived) {
    cout << "b is B"; // -> YES
}
```

How can I correctly identify the object type in [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11)?

Comment: `*a` is of type `A` and `*b` is of type `B` per their declaration.

Comment: Dynamic cast will work only with virtual but your code doesn't have any virtual function.

Comment: Best minimal solution similar to your code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7150bf0db7988cf1d2988aba99c72392-3b440a87a52fe2ae7c853c82f4c5144f

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some classes are polymorphic, some are non-polymorphic.

A polymorphic class has one or more virtual functions (possibly inherited), a non-polymorphic class has zero virtual functions.

Your A and B are non-polymorphic.

A polymorphic version of A and B will exhibit the behaviour you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    virtual ~A() {}; // add virtual function
};

class B : public A
{
};

A* a = new A();
A* a2 = new B();
B* b = new B();

int main()
{
    cout << (typeid(*a) == typeid(A)) << endl; // -> 1
    cout << (typeid(*a2) == typeid(A)) << endl; // -> 0 <-- CHANGED
    cout << (typeid(*b) == typeid(A)) << endl; // -> 0

    cout << (typeid(*a) == typeid(B)) << endl; // -> 0
    cout << (typeid(*a2) == typeid(B)) << endl; // -> 1 <-- CHANGED
    cout << (typeid(*b) == typeid(B)) << endl; // -> 1
}
```

Instances of a polymorphic class store the dynamic type of their *most derived object* at runtime.

(In your example `a2` is of type pointer-to-A, and is pointing at an object of type A, however this object is only a *base class subobject* of the *most dervived object* of type B.  What you want to get is the type of this most derived object B when querying `a2`. For this you need a polymorphic class.)

That is how polymorphic classes support `dynamic_cast` and `typeid` of the most derived object (as well as virtual function dispatch).

Non-polymorphic classes do not have this information, so they can only report the static type known at compile-time.  Non-polymorphic classes are more compact and efficient then polymorphic classes.  That is why not all C++ classes are polymorphic.  The language leaves it up to the programmer to chose the tradeoff between performance and functionality.  For example:

```
struct X { int x; };
struct Y : X {};
struct Z : Y {};
```

On my system non-polymorphic `Z` is `sizeof(Z) == 4 bytes`, same as an `int`.

```
struct X { int x; virtual ~X() {}; };
struct Y : X {};
struct Z : Y {};
```

Now after making `Z` polymorphic, `sizeof(Z) == 16 bytes`.  So an array of Z is now 300% larger, because each `Z` instance has to store its type information at runtime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221668/why-do-we-need-to-use-virtual-a-default-instead-of-virtual-a-in-c

Comment: @Sharth: No, [that's not true](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17222286/560648); you don't get it in _either_ case.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, @prosseek: Thank you for the correction!. I had thought that was one of the main reasons for the `= default` case.

Comment: @sharth: That would have been nice but alas not.

Comment: The comments are about a now-deleted incorrect statement that using `= default` instead of `{}` will inhibit default move constructor generation.

Comment: Note of course that you can get default move constructor generation back with `A(A&&) = default;`