# Check if method exists in descendant c++ class

Tags: c++, qt, class, methods, descendant

I have a base class (ANIMAL), a descendant class (BIRD) which adds method tweet.  I pass an instance of bird to a method expecting a class ANIMAL.

How I can that method check if the passed in object implements method tweet?

This in C++ (with Qt5 in case that matters)

Comment: You cannot unless using a CRTP or virtual polymorphism.

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve. No, not the one that you're asking, but the real problem for which you think the solution is to check if a subclass implements a particular method.

Comment: I need to pass objects into a class that MAY or MAY NOT offer particular features (i.e. methods).  I only want to call those methods if the descendant added those features.

Comment: Try dynamic_cast - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

Comment: so I would have to use instanceof and check every possible descendant class type (and know which class implements which methods)?  Seems tedious

Comment: You get a argument that has type animal. Just check if it is a bird. One line of code (assuming that you have a reasonable inheritance hierarchy

Comment: Downcasting is a codesmell. You should probably go for composition over inheritance.

Comment: There's also [RTTI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204487/checking-the-object-type-in-c11); but it's probably best addressed by re-thinking your design.

Comment: Others have mentioned dynamic_cast and RTTI and suggested redesign which I agree with completely. However, FYI in it's purest form what you are talking about is reflection which is not generally possible in C++, but can be achieved if you are willing to put a great deal of effort into it. See [How can I add reflection to my C++ application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application)

Comment: I think I have to rethink my design (as you've suggested) - combined with dynamic_cast.  Does that mean I define a pointer to the base class, then recast it to point to a descendant?

Comment: @Telium yes. The syntax will look like: child *p = dynamic_cast<child *>(pointerToBase). Keep in mind that if pointerToBase is not actually a child class, the dynamic_cast will fail and return nullptr.